# Prompt for file on application launch

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am making an application that can potentially be used on multiple computers by the same user.  I currently have implemented backup and restore functionality to keep the SQLite database synchronized.  However, when I install a new copy of the application, I would like to prompt the user to select a backup file (if applicable).

Initially, I thought that I would just put the logic in `MainPageViewModel.xaml` in the `OnNavigatedTo` method.  The problem with that is that it would run through that logic every time navigating back to `MainView`.  So, I thought that it would make sense to put it in `OnApplicationLaunchAsync` to only run once when the application is launched.

Here is my code currently:

```
    private async Task<StorageFile> SelectFileAsync()
    {
        StorageFile pickedFile = null;
        var settings = Container.Resolve<ISettings>();

        var picker = new FileOpenPicker();
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".sqlite");
        picker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;
        var file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();

        if (file != null)
        {
            var pickedFileToken = StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.Add(file);
            settings.BackupFileToken = pickedFileToken;

            pickedFile = file;
        }

        return pickedFile;
    }

    protected async override Task OnLaunchApplicationAsync(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        var navigationService = Container.Resolve<INavigationService>();
        var dialogService = Container.Resolve<IDialogService>();
        var settings = Container.Resolve<ISettings>();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(settings.BackupFileToken))
        {
            var backupFile =
                await StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.GetFileAsync(settings.BackupFileToken);
            var properties = await backupFile.GetBasicPropertiesAsync();

            dialogService.Show(string.Format("Backup file found: {0}\r\n" +
                                             "Modified date: {1}", backupFile.Path, properties.DateModified), "");

            navigationService.Navigate(Experiences.Main);
        }
        else
        {
            navigationService.Navigate(Experiences.Blank);

            //dialogService.Show("No backup file specified. Please choose a backup file location.", "");

            // TODO: load blank page, then select backup file location, then navigate to main page
            await SelectFileAsync();
        }

        // do not need to return Task.FromResult when OnLaunchApplicationAsync() is async
        //return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
```

As you can see, if the `BackupFileToken` exists, it will check the properties of the file and display a dialog with the file path and last modified date.  My problem lies in the situation where it is a new installation/the backup token doesn't exist.

If I try to display a dialog before the `FileOpenPicker` then the application crashes.  I thought perhaps adding a blank view to navigate to, then display the dialog and `FileOpenPicker`.  It just seems like there should be a simpler way to accomplish this (without the need for extra views).

Can someone recommend a way to prompt the user to select a file when the application launches, but let them know the purpose of the `FileOpenPicker`?

I am aware that my `await SelectFileAsync()` is losing its return value, this is a temporary situation for testing purposes.  I will be sure to assign the return value to the relevant variable once I have found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the override

`protected override void OnWindowCreated(WindowCreatedEventArgs args)` in `App.xaml.cs`

which is also called once for the creation of the main window.

Comment: I don't think this will work. here is some of the docs on MSDN:

"This method is called once for the creation of the main window, once for each hosted window, and once each time CreateNewView is called. "

Comment: Sure it will not work for every App but it's depending on the implementation of the views.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I will give this a try this evening and see if it yields a different result than having the logic in `OnLaunchApplicationAsync`